# Feature generation using PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data (used for predicting earthquakes [details](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/LANL-Earthquake-Prediction/data)) which has 2 columns and I want to generate new features from the data. The approach is based on [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/abhishek/quite-a-few-features-1-51/notebook) but I want to use PySpark. Basically I want to group the data in segments (say 1000 entries) and created new features from the same like mean, standard deviation, percentile, etc.

| acoustic_data | time_to_failure |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 1.4690999832 |
| 6 | 1.4690999821 |

I am trying to figure out how to do the same using PySpark. I can think of adding a new row and say I want to group by 2 entries I can repeat the index so that I can use `groupBy('idx').count()` to group them in chunks and then create the features. That said I am still not sure what code would create the `idx` column on the dataframe in that format.

| idx | acoustic_data | time_to_failure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 1.4690999832 |
| 1 | 6 | 1.4690999821 |
| 2 | 12 | 1.4690999832 |
| 2 | 6 | 1.4690999821 |

Is there a standard way to do this? Also, is there any standard way to create features in PySpark? I am new to this and appreciate any pointers.

Thanks.